# How to index arrays of descriptors in glsl?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have array of buffer descriptors, and each of them holds an array of different structs. What I need to do is pick each individually and tell what is inside. I, however, have barely any idea how glsl syntax works, and couldn't find anything online. Currently what I do is

```c
struct myData
{
    /.../
};
layout(set = 0, binding = 0)buffer a
{
    uint count;
    myData data[];
};

//or this

layout(set = 0, binding = 0)buffer a
{
    uint count;
    myData data[];
} A[2];

//And what I want is

layout(set = 0, binding = 0, index = 0)buffer a
{
    uint countMyData;
    myData data[];
};
layout(set = 0, binding = 0, index = 1)buffer b
{
    uint countIndices;
    uint indices[];
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have array of buffer descriptors, and each of them holds an array of different structs.

You have contradicted yourself. If you have an array of something, then each element is the same *kind* of something. Each element of an array of `int`s may have a different value, but each array element is an `int`.

That's what "array" means.

This is an either/or situation. Either the elements of a descriptor array use the same descriptor definition, or you create two different descriptor definitions, with two different binding locations, that represent two distinct descriptors.

Now, unsized descriptors that are arrayed can have different *sizes* for different array elements. But they're all going to use the same descriptor definition.

Comment: What I meant is that one descriptor has array of one type, and other has an array of other type, I added a piece of pseudo-code to clarify that

Comment: @user369070: I know what you want; I can see it in your pseudo-code. But the *descriptor definitions* are *different*. Therefore, an array of them would be an array with different *types* for each array element.

Comment: @user369070: And why do you need to access it by index rather than by name? GLSL is a statically-typed language; at compile time, the type of every expression *must be known*. Therefore, some hypothetical expression `A[index].data.whatever` must either be valid or invalid *at compile time*. If the descriptor array elements have different types, where `.data` may or may not be valid depending on `index`, then `index` *must be* a compile-time constant. And if that's the case, if the index is just written into the code, then just use the descriptor's name, which is *also* written into the code.

Comment: I had a mental image that buffer descriptors act like some sort of a pointer - I thought that it should be possible to pass all the buffers in an array and then define each array member individually, address them by name within shader after the definition.

Comment: @user369070: If you have an array of pointers in C++, do they not all point to the same type?

Comment: Void pointers don't have a type, and it is possible to explicitly say that pointer to one type is actually a pointer to other.

Comment: @user369070: That involves an *explicit cast* at the point of use. GLSL (and SPIR-V beneath it) has no such casting constructs. It also has no unions. GLSL (and SPIR-V) *really* don't want you playing games with the type system.